# Increasing font size in codename one?

Tags: java, fonts, codenameone

I'm trying to increase the font size of my components in Codename One but having a tough time.

using the NetBeans IDE, they have a pretty nifty theme generator/editor included as part of the codenameone package, but fonts only seem to have a small/medium/large option. For me, the pixel and millimeter options don't do anything.

Has anyone else run into this? Does anyone have tips on getting my fonts nice and large?

Answer (score 1):

The pixel and millimeter options only work for non-system fonts. If you place a ttf file in the src directory you should be able to define it as the font and then set its size to any arbitrary value.